# How to prove sup{$a_n + b_n$} $\leq$ sup{$a_n$} + sup{$b_k$}?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

{$a_n$} and {$b_k$} are two bounded real sequences.
How to prove sup{$a_n + b_n$}  $\leq$ sup{$a_n$} + sup{$b_k$} where {$a_n + b_n$} denotes {($a_n + b_n$) | $n ∈ \mathbb N^+ $}.

Comment: Hint: It suffices to proof that if $A\geq a_n$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N^+}$ and $B\geq b_k$ for all $k\in\mathbb{N^+}$, then $A+B\geq a_n+b_n$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N^+}$ (Why?).

Comment: @Uncountable: Got you. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\sup\{a_n\}+\sup\{b_n\}\geq a_k+b_k$ for all $k\in\mathbb{N}^+$, that is $\sup\{a_n\}+\sup\{b_n\}$ is a upper bound for $\{a_n+b_n\}$. Hence, $\sup\{a_n\}+\sup\{b_n\}\geq \sup\{a_n+b_n\}$, as $\sup\{a_n+b_n\}$ is the least upper bound.

Comment: duplicate $a_n$.

Comment: I forgot the "least" mean in least upper bound. Come on.